# Superclass Sinatra::Response

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra I'd like to use a custom class for the response object. My custom class would superclass Sinatra::Response. However, I can't find where Sinatra or Sinatra::Base actually creates the response object or decides what class to use for it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: is [this](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/c7655190128fdcc37b160d55e7afc4d4291789ce/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L130) what you are looking for ?

Comment: That might be it. I'll check it out. Thanks!